# How do I get pytest to submit a flask wtforms form correctly

Tags: flask, pytest, flask-wtforms

A few of my tests are failing repeatedly so I'm using the shortest one as an example for this question

test

```
    def test_delete_char(self):
    with self.client:
        start = characters.query.count() #num of entries in db
        self.client.post(
                url_for("delete", identity=1),
                follow_redirects=True)
        end = characters.query.count() #num of entries in db after deletion
        self.assertTrue(start > end) #check if delete has gone through
```

route

```
@app.route("/delete/<identity>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete(identity):
form = DeleteForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    char = characters.query.filter_by(id=identity).first()
    db.session.delete(char)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))
return render_template("delete.html", form=form, identity=identity, title="Delete")
```

When running this function on the website manually there are no issues. Using pytest I can see that it doesn't get past if form.validate_on_submit(): in the delete function. I can only conclude that my self.client.post is wrong but I have no idea what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In my setUp function I had set WTF_CSRF_ENABLE=False instead of WTF_CSRF_ENABLED=False. this meant it was looking for a CSRF token that wasn't provided whenever a wtforms containing function was tested. Moral of the story is don't use vim/an editor without error highlighting